# Creating a drop down menu with Jquery (Show / Hide item)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to have a section of text to appear when I click something.  Trying to do this with jquery, but having issues.  I am new to jquery so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Html code: (i want 'VVVVVVVVVVVV' to be the item I click to show something else)

```
<div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
        <span>
            <h6 class="payment-item-title">VISA ending in 5555</h6>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
        <span>
            <h6 class="payment-item-title">12/2017</h6>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4"  align="center">
        <span id="v-btn">
            <h6>
                <b>VVVVVVVVVVVV</b>
            </h6>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML code ( that I want to appear from a click):

```
<div align="center" id="content-content" class="sub-nav" style="background-color: #939393">
    <div class="row" align="center">

        <div class="col-sm-4" align="right">
            <span>
                <h6 class="payment-section-header-title">name on card</h6>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4" align="right">
            <span>
                <h6 class="payment-section-header-title">billing address</h6>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center">
        <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
            <span>
                <h6 class="payment-item-title">Jonny Smith</h6>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6" align="left">
                <span>
                    <h6 class="payment-item-title">
                        Jonny Smith
                        <br />
                        123 Fake Street
                        <br />
                        Township, NJ
                        <br />
                        201-555-5554
                    </h6>
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5" align="center">
            <h6>
                <button type="button" align="center">Edit</button>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1" align="center">
            <h6>
                <button type="button" align="center">Delete</button>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#v-btn').click(function() {
        alert("im here");
        $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
</script>
```

Set this at the top:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is some CSS for the process:

```
#content-content.sub-nav{
    display: none;
}


#content-content.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why you put `h3` inside of `span`?

Comment: Kindly specify the problem exactly you are running into.

Comment: There is no problem with your code, worked fine for me!

Comment: I cannot get the 'VVVVV' to work so I get a section of text to appear when I click VVVVV.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani where you able to show something when you clicked VVVV, because that is what i want, to show and hide a section with each click to VVVV

Comment: As @MehdiDehghani has pointed your code is working fine. It is toggling the display of the section you mentioned.

Comment: Your code has no error, and by clicking on `VVVVV`, section will show/hide successfully, just please note, you need to add you code block, after `jQuery library` link. I don't know if you did this wrong.

Comment: What would I need to add after the link?  I just have the link and then the code for the jquery under that

Comment: So, that's fine, I mean you need to add link of `jQuery`, then add `<script> ... </script>` block, of course inside of `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#v-btn').click(function() {            
    var $elem = $(this).find('h6 > b');
    $elem.text(); // will be VVVVVV
    alert("im here");
    $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the on-click event of the span to change the visibility of the content.

**HTML:**

```
<span id='v-btn'>VVVVVVVVVVVVVV</span>

<div class='sub-nav'>
    <p>all types of content in here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sub-nav {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#v-btn').on('click',function(){
        $('.sub-nav').toggle();
        //or to just show:
        //$('.sub-nav').show();
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/02bge9ch/1/

Comment: would uncommenting '$('.sub-nav').show();'   allow VVVVVV to show and hide the content I want?  I want VVVV to do both

Comment: @Drew Calling toggle(), like as is, will toggle the visibility of all elements with class sub-nav. So when v-btn is clicked, it will set sub-nav's visibility to the opposite of its current state.

Comment: forgive me if this is a dumb question, but I am used to defining class with double quotes but I see here that you are using single quotes for everything.  I am still not able to see a result from my side, could that be the issue I am having?

Comment: @Drew single and double quotes are both valid as representing strings in markup, so that wouldn't make a difference. Take a look at the fiddle in my answer, maybe seeing how it works will help.

Comment: I actually figured out the issue.  We are using Angular so jquery wont work apparently.  Here is the code that help:  app.controller('PaymentMethodsCtrl' , [ '$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
 $scope.active = true;
 $scope.showCardDetails = function() {
  $scope.active = !$scope.active;
  
  //test for the data
  //if scope.active{
   //set data here..
  //}
  
  
 }                  
}]);           -my question is..I now have to set the data, within the if scope.active...should I just put in the html for what I want to appear?  How do I set the data? @James

Comment: @Drew I'd recommend creating a new question for a separate issue like this

Comment: what is best way to word the issue?  Since I am new to this, stack is telling me I may be banned from asking future questions soon.  I believe I need to set data to a scope? is that the best way to word it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I managed to figure out
Since I am using Angular, i cannot use jquery so here is the solution.

Add this to my payment-methods.js file and erase the jquery from my html page:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp.payment-methods',[])

app.controller('PaymentMethodsCtrl' , [ '$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
$scope.active = true;
$scope.showCardDetails = function() {
    $scope.active = !$scope.active;


}                  
}]);
```

i add this to the content I want to appear:

```
ng-class="{'sub-nav' : active}" class="card-details"
```

and add this line of code to the item I want to show and hide the content:

```
<div class="col-sm-4"  align="center">
            <span ng-click="showCardDetails()" id="v-btn">V</span>
        </div>
```